# Cannot implicity convert int to bool

Tags: c#

Okay, so I'm getting a "cannot convert int to bool" error.

I'm trying to convert this VB .net code:

```vb
Function GetChecksum(ByVal Source As String) As Long
    Dim iVal, Weight, CheckHold, CheckSum As Long
    Weight = 1
    CheckSum = 0
    For iVal = 1 To Len(Source)
        CheckHold = Asc(Mid$(Source, iVal, 1)) * Weight
        CheckSum = CheckSum + CheckHold
        Weight = Weight + 2
    Next iVal
    GetChecksum = CheckSum Mod &H7FFFFFFF
End Function
```

I've gotten up to here:

```
    public long getCheckSum(string source)
    {
        long iVal, weight, checkgold, checksum = new long();
        weight = 1;
        checksum = 0;
        for (iVal = 1; Strings.Len(source);)
        {

        }
    }
```

The problem is the "For (iVal = 1; Strings.Len(source);)" code. I am using "Microsoft.VisualBasic". I just don't know what to do right now. If you could help me that'd be great.

Comment: Before anyone else adds or votes up anything containing `iVal = 1`, look at the docs for [Mid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829(v=VS.90).aspx), where it states that indexing with this function is 1-based. The C# equivalent must use `iVal = 0` to be correct.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you need to set your loop correctly. In C#, a for loop (generally) follows the following format:

```
for(initializer; conditional check; evaluation)
```

- initializer is where you set variables like iVal = 1
- conditional check is where you determine the bounds of the for loop
- evaluation is usually where you increment a variable

In your code, you have an integer, Strings.Len(source), as the conditional check, which is expecting a boolean response so it's failing.

Your for loop opener should look something like this:

```
for (iVal = 1; iVal < source.Length; iVal++)
```

That's assuming your logic is 0 < iVal < length of source string.

As an aside, the way you check the length of a string in C# is with the .Length property, rather than using the Strings.Len() function.

Answer (score 4):

```
    for (iVal = 1; iVal < source.Length; iVal++)
    {

    }
```

The middle section is a condition.

Comment: This most likely is 1 iteration too short.

Answer (score 3):

You will need:

```
  for (iVal = 1; iVal <= source.Length; ival += 1)
```

But be aware this loops through 1..source.Length,
not the more common (in C#)  0..source.Length-1

Answer (score 0):

Your For syntax should looks something like this :

```
For(ival = 1; source.Length; ival++)
{
  // your code here
}
```

ival++ will replace the "Next" in VB.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have already solved your problem, I only want to add for future reference that you might want to check out [Convert VB to C#](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/).

I've used it myself on a number of occasions with pretty good results.

Answer (score 0):

Standard syntax of `for` loop:

```
for(counter initialize; counter compare; counter increment) {}
```

The comparison expects a `bool`, you're providing an `int` with `Strings.Len(source)`, which returns some number, not a Boolean value like `true` or `false`.

Try

```
for(iVal = 1; iVal < String.Len(source); iVal++)
```

You may want to use `<=` since your starting at 1 or set `iVal` to 0

Answer (score 0):

Rather than translate the `for` loop literally into C#, I'd use a `foreach`, as you're doing a straightforward iteration over the elements of a sequence (each char in the string):

```
public long getCheckSum(string source)
{
  long checkHold = 0, checkSum = 0, weight = 1;

  foreach (char ch in source)
  {
    checkHold = (long)ch * weight;
    checkSum += checkHold;
    weight += 2;
  }

  return checkSum % 0x7FFFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you want

```
for (iVal = 1; iVal <= source.Length; iVal++)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to leave iVal alone (because you need it "pure" for something later)

```
for(i = iVal; i <= source.Length; i++)
{
    //your code here.
}
```

Comment: It came from the mystical land of "Typo" in the province of "typing too fast."  I'll fix it.